# Get posts from my feed made by others Facebook via Graph API 2.0 without FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want get posts from my timeline posted by others via **Graph Api**.

Is there a way to accomblish this without using FQL.

The Problem is that **FQL** will **no longer be available** after version 2.0 of the Graph Api.